# How to copy and paste specific information in a same doc using Google App Script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm very new using GAS what I'm trying to do is to copy some information that is already on the bottom of my doc to anywhere I want in my docs, this should work just by copying the information and paste it at the place I desire, but I want it to be done with Google App Script because it's a daily task and it's easier to do it with a function, instead of copying and pasting manually. Searching on how to do this, I found a lot of information about how to do it on Spreadsheets, but I needed it to be done on Google Docs. How can I do that?

If someone can guide me or send me a link to another similar question that would be very helpful, I don't know where to start.

***This is what I have until now, I get all the data of the current doc and set it again to the page, the code gives me problems because it deletes my other information, also it selects all the doc's information. I want to select a piece of specific information and don't copy the content style.***

```js
function copyPasteInfo() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var body = doc.getBody();
  var notesText = body.getText();
  body.appendPageBreak();
  body.setText(notesText);
}
```

***Link to the doc document***
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1s2TCspXbjvHVurwhIWSdwJ_hMcZIoLTKj4FAB82nmhM/edit
***Video example of how what i want to do***

https://www.screencast.com/t/UmEon8Fm0lPe

***Picture of the information i'm trying to copy and paste to the bottom of my doc***
[image]

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from `i'm trying is to copy information that is already on the bottom of my doc to the anywhere i want in my docs`, I cannot understand about your goal. Can I ask you about the detail of your goal?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#replaceText(String,String)

Comment: Could you share a Doc with some dummy data? And also an example of  how you want the data to be set in your Doc please

Comment: @Tanaike Yes no problem with asking me more, i have a table in my doc that i need to copy and paste on somewhere else of my doc, for example if i have these words : first,second,third i want with a function to copy the word third and put it before second. That is an example of what im trying but with words instead of tables

Comment: @albertovielma See the updated question, i want to put my table the one you see in my doc or in my question between specific content of my doc

Comment: @Cooper By your short answer of that link i really don't know where to start or implement that in my script, maybe can you explain more.Even that i updated my question so you can see better of what i'm talking about

Comment: Thank you for replying. I noticed that an answer has already been posted. I think that it will resolve your issue.

Comment: @Tanaike well it doesn't solve it

Comment: Thank you for replying. I think that the answerer might be thinking the modified script. So how about waiting for replying from the answerer?

Comment: @Tanaike Yes i will wait and if it doesn't answer we retake the question, thanks for answering so fast

Comment: @Tanaike I didn't receive good answers could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understood your question, this code will help you to achieve your goal.

```
let body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();

function moveTable() {
  // Get the last table and the previous table found in your Doc
  const [previousTable, bottomTable] = getDesireTables();
  // Make a copy of your last table 
  const bottomTableCopy = bottomTable.copy();
  // Get the previous table's index
  const previousTableIndex = body.getChildIndex(previousTable);
  // Insert the last table's copy under the previous table  in your Doc
  body.insertTable(previousTableIndex + 1, bottomTableCopy);
  // Remove the original last table
  body.removeChild(bottomTable);
}

function getDesireTables(){
  const tablesArr = body.getTables().slice(-3);
  // Get the parent element type to check if it's a cell
  const parentELementType = tablesArr[tablesArr.length - 1].getParent().getType();
  if(parentELementType ===  DocumentApp.ElementType.TABLE_CELL){
    // If there's a table inside a table, return this
    return tablesArr.slice(0, 2);
  }
  else{
    return tablesArr.slice(-2);
  }
}
```

What I did was to get the last two tables in the Doc, then I made a copy of the last one and with the index of the previous one, I inserted it under the previous one.

### Edit

I noticed you had a table inside a table. therefore I added the `getDesireTables` function. Which it will check if your bottom table has a table inside.

### Docs

These are the docs I used to help you:

- [getTables()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#gettables).
- [copy()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/table#copy).
- [insertTable(childIndex, table)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#inserttablechildindex-table).

Comment: Yes you correctly understood what i'm trying to do, the thing is that i run your code and give me problems                                                                                                                                                     1.Says this `body.removeChild(bottomTable); Element does not contain the specified child element`                                                                                                                                                  2.Doesn't copy all table an paste it, only paste the parte that says `Deadline` and `Description`.

Comment: Could you please make public the Doc you shared? In that way I could use your same exact tables and the what's happening

Comment: Yes here it is https://docs.google.com/document/d/1s2TCspXbjvHVurwhIWSdwJ_hMcZIoLTKj4FAB82nmhM/edit?usp=sharing